# Find the longest characters string in list with tuples

Tags: python, tuples, variable-length

I am looking for the longest characters string in a list with tuple couples. But only on the first element of all tuples.

```py
VMT = [('T_WIN2019_04.2020', 'Microsoft Windows Server 2016 (64-bit)'), ('T_CENTOS_7.8_04.2020', 'CentOS 7 (64-bit)'), ('T_WIN2016_05.2019', 'Microsoft  Windows Server 2016 (64-bit)'), ('T_W2019_STD_EN', 'Microsoft Windows Server 2016   (64-bit)'), ('T_W2016_DTC_EN', 'Microsoft Windows Server 2016 (64-bit)')]
```

I use this :

```py
max(VMT, key=len)[0]
'T_WIN2019_04.2020'
```

T_WIN2019_04.2020 = 16 chars

Should be :

```py
'T_CENTOS_7.8_04.2020'
```

T_CENTOS_7.8_04.2020 = 20 chars

I think the calculation is done on the whole tuple but not the first element of tuples.

Comment: You're finding the longest *tuple*. If you want to compare the lengths of the tuples' elements, your key function needs to do that.

Comment: Flatten the list: `max([item for tpl in VMT for item in tpl], key=len)` >> 'Microsoft Windows Server 2016 (64-bit)'

Comment: True, but I would like to find the longest string only in the first element of tuples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key` on `max` function should be the length of the first element of the tuples:

```py
max(VMT, key=lambda t: len(t[0]))[0]
```

```
'T_CENTOS_7.8_04.2020'
```